# Preventing infomation from being searched

Tags: user-profile

How do you prevent other users from searching another users information in a list? I have a list called student database where users who gain access to site login and fill out form and update there files. How do I prevent others users from searching other users information in the search engine?

Answer (score 0):

This is by default functionality in SharePoint, if an user doesn't have permission in the list items, those items will not be displayed in the search result for that user... SharePoint search service takes care this permission automatically..... no need to handle it from our end.

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate other users that share the same list to view other people information. example SSN